# How to stop a server with kill-9 command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, terminal

Im unable to get my server to connect to my frontend and am trying to kill it with the command kill -9 PID but im unsure which PID to kill... Can killing the wrong one be detrimental ?

when i run sudo lsof -i :5000 to see whats running i get back 
COMMAND    PID    FD    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME 
ControlCe  402   22u  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN) 
ControlCe  402   23u  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN) 
ControlCe  402   28u  TCP localhost:commplex-main->localhost:51632 (ESTABLISHED) 
Google    1575   21u  TCP localhost:51632->localhost:commplex-main (ESTABLISHED)

Can someone explain what all of this means and how to know which to kill...

**ERRORS**: 
 Access to localhost was denied You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403 when checking if my backend node server is running on localhost:5000/api/hello. 
**Aswell as** 
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000

Here is the backend package.json

```
{
  "name": "example-create-react-app-express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && yarn start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

The client side package.json

```
{
  "name": "express-server-demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.7.1",
    "firebase": "^9.4.1",
    "javascript-time-ago": "^2.3.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-time-ago": "^7.1.3",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.2.21",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Im trying to run both the client and server with the command:
npm start from the client folder

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's either the first two or the first three.

Comment: uhhh............

Answer (score 0):

You need the process id, and the easiest way to get that is to do

```sh
px axu | grep someFragmentOfYourProcessName
```

Then grab the pid.

First do  `kill pid`  Some servers will shut down gracefully if they're not jammed up.

If that fails, do `kill -9 pid`  -9 is a pretty abrupt way to stop a process. Avoid it unless necessary. Do your best to avoid it for production servers handling  other peoples' data.

Comment: i tried px axu | grep 5000 that command didnt work. cant you check the process ID by running sudo lsof -i :5000

Comment: He meant, "`ps asx`" (or "`ps aux`"- they're both valid)